# How to update sticky menu's CSS positioning on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've built a sticky navbar based on [an example from W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp). It's working very well — except when I resize the window, the alignment of the nav menu to the page content is incorrect.

You'll see that I've got some code that finds the correct offset for left side of menu, by checking another element on the page. It then adds some left padding to align it properly. (Without this, the `position:fixed` value just sends the sticky nav to the far left of the page).

This works great on scroll! However, if the window is resized horizontally, that left padding value doesn't update.

I've tried a few iterations of `$(window).resize` but haven't been able to get it to work. I'm sure it's an easy line of code I'm just not figuring out. Thanks in advance!

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    // Get the navbar
    var navbar = document.getElementById("app");

    // Get the offset position of the navbar
    var sticky = $("#app").offset().top

    // Find correct offset for left side of menu (by checking #title element)
    var element = document.getElementById('title');
    var leftPos = element.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.scrollX;
    var roundLeft = (Math.round(leftPos)) - 5;

    // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        navbar.style.cssText = "padding-left:" + roundLeft + "px!important";    

      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        navbar.style.cssText = "padding-left:inherit";
      }
    }

}, 4000);
```

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99);
    z-index: 9 !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #999;
}
```

(I'm using `setTimeout` because our Shiny app takes a few seconds to load and for the content to populate.)

Comment: Why don't you want to use CSS' position: sticky itself?

Comment: @Kotofenum I .... guess I didn't know that it existed. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pure CSS solution with `position: sticky`

It does have acceptable percentage of browser support:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Since it's just the styling, it may be fine to show it static in the old browsers.

Comment: Very embarrassed that I didn't know about this. :/